# Bootstrap (on Laravel) - Header dropdown becomes transparent on one page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown, opacity

I seem to have an issue with one of my pages I'm trying to layout. I implemented FullCalendar and added it to one of my pages/views, I'm now noticing that my header dropdown when it overlays on top of where the calendar begins -- the dropdown isn't opaque/forced overtop of the underlaying content like how it is on all other pages. Attached is the example of what is happening.

Any ideas? If I should be posting my CSS let me know. It's the default for FullCalendar & Bootstrap with no modifications.

Here is the view HTML/classes applied to the content it's not drawing 'over/on top of':

```
@section('content')
@include('layouts.headers.cards')
<div class="container-fluid mt--7"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card shadow">
                <div class="card-header border-0">   
                        <div class="col-14">
                            <div id='calendar'></div>  
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @include('layouts.footers.auth')
</div>
@endsection
```

[image: Dropdown background not opaque]

Comment: Did you try to add a "z-index" on the dropdown menu?

Comment: These are a couple of the CSS declarations for the .dropdown-menu class in my theme:

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#calendar{
  z-index: 999999;
  position: relative;
}
```

<< That should fix it!

Read: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Tried that and the result looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/Qw2Hr9J.png

Comment: Try z-index: 9999999999999

Comment: Or give a z-index/position to the other div (that is overlapping) with a z-index that is less then 999999

Comment: Being finicky! Doesn't seem to want to work.This is a link to the FullCalendar css (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.css) -- not sure if anything in there is affecting this. The dropdown is opaque over other containers on other pages.

Comment: I kept messing around and eventually doing this in-line solved it. Many thanks for your suggestion as it ultimately lead me to the solution!

 <div id='calendar' style='z-index: 0 !important;position: relative !important;'></div>

Comment: Ah you needed some !importants to finish the job :P Good work. Accept my answer as the correct one please!